# how to insert whole dataframe in mysql using executemany python

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to insert newDF in my `mysql` Database at one time using executemany

```
x=[
    [[3141],[3141],[3169],[3251],[3285],[3302]],
    [[5000],[3141],[3169],[3251],[3285],[3302]]
]

y=[
    [[5],[7],[5],[2],[3],[8]],
    [[6],[5],[6],[5],[3],[6]]
]
newDF=pd.DataFrame()
newDF[['x']]=x
newDF[['y']]=y`
sql = "INSERT INTO new_table (`x`,`y`) VALUES (?,?)" number_of_rows = cursor.executemany(sql,list(np.int64(newDF)))
```

Comment: Hey, just letting you know, use the `%s` operator is a bad practice, if one of you inputs is poisoned you could be having a bad day(here is a comical example: https://xkcd.com/327/). In Python you can use the `?` operator for all the `execute` like functions to avoid sql-injection exploits: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html (it is near the top)

Comment: You need to write an actual question in the body of your question, not just in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with executemany. However, I've used pandas.dataframe.to_sql successfully. You can find that [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). In my case, I was using sqlalchemy and pymysql libraries to accomplish this.

This is not real code, but should be a reasonable outline; consider m to be the dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pymysql as mysql
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from pandas.io import sql

engine=create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:password@host:port/db_name')
m.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: how can I check sequence of  field
like insert into table (field1,field2)

Comment: I believe that it matches by column names. In your case, it would match x & y to the table. I believe it will also create a new table if there is not currently one matching the name.